# How to set specific height for chartJs background color in terms of yAxis value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, html2canvas

I have a line chart using `chartJs` [see app.component.ts on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-jmxaz9?file=app/app.component.ts)

[image: current line chart]

As you can see `backgroundColor: 'rgba(250,174,50,1)'` only gives color for whole chart.What I need is background color until a specific `yAxis` value.In this example for example until 200 I want to see orange color and rest is white like below.

[image: desired line chart]

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `afterLayout` hook to create a linear gradient through [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) and assign it to the `backgroundColor` property of the dataset.

```
plugins: [{
  afterLayout: c => {
    let dataset = c.data.datasets[0];
    let thresholdValueIndex = dataset.data.indexOf(dataset.fillThreshold);
    let xAxis = c.scales["x-axis-0"];
    let xRight = xAxis.getPixelForTick(thresholdValueIndex);
    let gradientFill = c.ctx.createLinearGradient(xAxis.left, 0, xRight, 0);
    gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgb(250,174,50");
    gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgb(250,174,50");
    gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "white");
    dataset.backgroundColor = gradientFill;
  }
}],
```

This code expects the property `fillThreshold` to be defined on the dataset, its value must correspond to a value also contained in the `data` array.

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-7fmwgk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).